# Div is sitting directly on top of another div

Tags: html, css

I am following a tutorial. I found on making a product showcase using css, it looks great but I want to add more to my page.

Underneath I would like to put a slider with more images, add text and include a footer.

However, when I add the slider, it just sits directly on top of my product showcase and the page doesn't scroll.  I have searched and tried so many options but nothing is working for me - any advice?

```css
     html, body {
      width: 100%;
    
    }
    /*----------------------------
        Styling the presentation
    -----------------------------*/
    #impress {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #impress:not(.impress-not-supported) .step{
        opacity:0.4;
    }
    
    #impress .step{
        width:700px;
        height: 600px;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
    
        -moz-transition:1s opacity;
        -webkit-transition:1s opacity;
        transition:1s opacity;
    }
    
    #impress .step.active{
        opacity:1;
    }
    
    #impress h2{
        font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
        font-size: 42px;
        color:#444648;
        position:absolute;
        /* z-index:10; */
    }
    
    #impress p{
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color:#27333f;
        position:absolute;
        /* z-index:10; */
    }
    
    #impress img{
      position:absolute;
      /* z-index:1; */
    }
    
    .arrow{
     width:32px;
     height:54px;
     background:url('./img/arrows.png') no-repeat;
     position:fixed;
     top:50%;
     margin-top:-27px;
     cursor:pointer;
     text-indent:-9999px;
     overflow:hidden;
     opacity:0.8;
     border:none !important;
     text-decoration:none !important;
    
     -moz-transition:0.2s opacity;
     -webkit-transition:0.2s opacity;
     transition:0.2s opacity;
    }
    
    .arrow:hover{
     opacity:1;
    }
    
    #arrowLeft{
     left:45px;
    }
    
    #arrowRight{
     right:45px;
     background-position:top right;
    }
    
    
    /*----------------------------
        Slide 1 - Intro
    -----------------------------*/
    /*
    #impress #intro{
        width: 500px;
    }
    */
    
    #intro h2{
      left: 300px;
      top: 120px;
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    #intro p {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.4;
      top: 230px;
      left: 340px;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    #phone-one{
      right: 300px;
    }
    
    /*----------------------------
        Slide 2
    -----------------------------*/
    
    #simplicity h2 {
      margin-top: 130px;
      left: -40px;
    }
    
    #simplicity p {
      width: 50%;
      margin-top: 220px;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    
    #phone-two {
      left: 300px;
    }
    
    /*----------------------------
        Slide 3
    -----------------------------*/
    #connect h2 {
      margin: 350px 30px 0 -30px;
    }
    
    #connect p {
      margin-top: 440px;
      line-height: 1.4;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    #phone-three {
      bottom: 90px;
    }
    
    /*----------------------------
        Slide 4
    -----------------------------*/
    #upload h2 {
      margin-top: 120px;
      left: -100px;
    }
    
    #upload p {
      width: 60%;
      margin-top: 210px;
      line-height: 1.4;
      left: -60px;
    }
    
    #phone-four {
      left: 250px;
      bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    /*----------------------------
        Slide 5
    -----------------------------*/
    #music h2 {
      margin: 0px 50px;
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    #music p {
      text-align: left;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 80px;
      line-height: 1.4;
      top: 10px;
    }
    
    #phone-five {
      top: 100px;
      left: 50px;
    }
```

```html
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Impressive CSS3 Product Showcase | Tutorialzine Demo</title>
    
            <!-- Google Webfonts and our stylesheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow|Open+Sans:300">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>
    
      <body>
    
        <section class="header-section">
        <div id="impress" class="impress-not-supported">
    
                <!-- The Slides Will Go Here -->
    
                <!-- The first slide retains its default position. We could omit the data attributes -->
        <div id="intro" class="step" data-x="0" data-y="0">
            <h2>Quality Watch Photography</h2>
            <p>We take the very best quality, realistic photography <br> of your new and pre-owned watches. We understand <br>the challenges in photographing different styles of <br>watch, carefully considering each component to ensure <br>the perfect representation of your watch.</p>
            <img src="img/watch-one.png" width="700" height="700" alt="Galaxy Nexus" id="phone-one">
        </div>
    
        <!-- We are offsetting the second slide, rotating it and making it 1.8 times larger -->
        <div id="simplicity" class="step" data-x="1100" data-y="1200" data-scale="1.8" data-rotate="190">
            <h2>The Devil Is In The Detail</h2>
            <p>We photograph using the ’focus stack' method to create the very best fully focused photography.
              We position your watch and take many images closing in on each tiny detail, sometimes up to 35
              images and then carefully select, process and blend to create one super crisp, detailed photograph.
              We undertake all our processing and retouching in house to ensure quality in every photograph we take.</p>
            <img src="img/watch-two.png" width="700" height="700" alt="Galaxy Nexus" id="phone-two">
        </div>
    
        <!-- Same for the rest.. -->
        <div id="connect" class="step" data-x="-300" data-y="600" data-scale="0.2" data-rotate="270">
            <h2>Studio Or We Come To You</h2>
            <p>We understand your watches are precious and extremely valuable, we are fully set up to photograph here in our studio, but we have created our own bespoke portable studio so we can come to you and photograph your watches in the security of your own home, shop or office.</p>
            <img src="img/watch-three.png" width="700" height="700" alt="Galaxy Nexus" id="phone-three">
        </div>
    
        <div id="upload" class="step" data-x="-200" data-y="1500" data-rotate="180">
            <h2>Character & Condition</h2>
            <p>We have the expertise and experience when photographing your vintage and pre owned watches. We work with retailers, dealers and auction houses photographing watches to capture the character and condition of each unique watch showing your customer a highly detailed and accurate photograph of the watch for sale.</p>
            <img src="img/watch-four.png" width="700" height="700" alt="Galaxy Nexus" id="phone-four">
        </div>
    
        <div id="music" class="step" data-x="-1200" data-y="1000" data-scale="0.8" data-rotate="270">
            <h2>Part Of Your Team</h2>
            <p>We love working with client’s from all aspects of the watch industry, from small independent jewellers to established Swiss brands, unique micro brands to bespoke watch customisation and watch dealers and auction houses. We are fully client-focused and always here to provide you with the very best photographs of your watches.
    
    </p>
            <img src="img/watch-five.png" width="700" height="700" alt="Galaxy Nexus" id="phone-five">
        </div>
      </div>
    
    
            <a id="arrowLeft" class="arrow">&lt;</a>
          <a id="arrowRight" class="arrow">&gt;</a>
    
      </section>
    
      <section class="gallery-one">
        <div class="white-watches">
          <h4>watch gallery</h4>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
    
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="./img/watch-slider-one.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
        </div>
    
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./img/watch-slider-two.jpg" alt="Chicago">
        </div>
    
        <div class="item">
          <img src="./img/jewel-slider-one.jpg" alt="New York">
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: may be you can provide a working demo to look, i have inspected your code and see that the section above `myCarousel` div has inline style of `float:left`, try removing that float and the carousal div will be under the table section.

Comment: Could you please share you JS also and Can you replicate your problem in a code snippet ?

Comment: I haven't used any floats.  I would love to show you a demo but I'm not sure how I do that.  I have the whole folder on my desktop as I am using atom?

Comment: why do you position everything inside impress absolutely?  Seems like that will be the source of your problems

Comment: Hi Pete, that's what the tutorial code was, when I take it out the images move somewhere else

Comment: This is what the demo looks like http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/02/css3-product-showcase/ when clicking next or pushing spacebar, the images and text move

Comment: Looks like that's meant to be a full page slider, perhaps try adding height 100vh to your impress container so it takes the full page height and pushes things after it underneath

Comment: Hi Pete, I tried your suggestion.  If I put it in #impress it does the same thing, just sits on top if I put it in .header-section the slider disappears and I still can't scroll.  It does look great as a full page slider but I really want to be able to put some info underneath - any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Adding, 
     Clear: both;
to your slider div in your css file should do the trick

Comment: Why will this do the trick (just a nudge for a better answer)?